# Смена картинки на CSS. Анимация

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-animation

Нужно чтобы при наведении на слово менялась картинка и появлялась соответствующая. Я делаю, но у меня только меняется при наведении на последнее слово. В чем ошибка?

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c10106/u78663797/d_220b9246.jpg);
  width: 336px;
  height: 600px;
  transition: 1s;
}

p1:hover+.pic {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.flamp.ru/4f1fded18c548c909cc4bdda9cfdb33c_100_100.jpg);
}

p2:hover+.pic {
  background-image: url(https://d37ta6l1gshlok.cloudfront.net/user-thumbnail/4049/22787178_0-100.jpg);
}

p3:hover+.pic {
  background-image: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c7008/v7008345/66190/-1evfBqn24E.jpg?ava=1);
}

p4:hover+.pic {
  background-image: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c10058/u88208531/d_01d64824.jpg);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 1</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 2</p2>
<p3 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 3</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 4</p4>

<div class="pic"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***p1:hover ~ .pic***

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c10106/u78663797/d_220b9246.jpg);
  width: 336px;
  height: 600px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: contain;
}

p1:hover,
p2:hover {
  color: red;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.flamp.ru/4f1fded18c548c909cc4bdda9cfdb33c_100_100.jpg);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c7008/v7008345/66190/-1evfBqn24E.jpg?ava=1);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 1</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer;">slovo 2</p2>

<div class="pic"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если нужно чтобы не на одна картинку заменить на 2 или больше картинок. Как тогда быть?

Comment: 2 картинки фоновые в один блок?

Comment: вроде того, имею ввиду при наведении на slovo1 появлялась одна картинка и через секунду уже другая. и так с каждым словом

Comment: Timur,  этот вариант который ты реализовал, очень ограничен....   css на большее не способен... То что ты описал в последнем комментарии можно реализовать с ***js***

Comment: можете показать на js примерно как должно быть?

Comment: @timur, ты новый вопрос оформи, опиши, что ты хочешь...Выложи `html, css`, а с `js` помогут... Не я так другие...

Comment: @не получилось все-таки сделать так