# Не работет :hover в выподающем меню

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

В общем я хочу чтобы объекты класса `.line` при наведении на `.list` передвигались. Далее я планирую объектам класса `.line` назначить разные `transition delay`.

Или эта магия работает только с `ul and li` и я зря потратил 3-4 часа.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Federant', cursive;
  font-size: 1vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  margin: 5vw;
  width: 10vw;
}

p {
  border-bottom: 0.1vh solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2vh;
  background: rgb(151, 101, 101);
  width: 10vw;
  height: 6vh;
}

.line,
.line2,
.line3 {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  left: 500%;
}

.line2 {
  top: -22vh;
  display: none;
}

.line3 {
  top: -45vh;
  left: 25vw;
  display: none;
}

.list:hover .line {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p class="list"> Paragraf</p>
  <p class="list2"> Paragraf</p>
  <p class="list3"> Paragraf</p>
  <p class="line">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line2">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line2">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line2">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line2">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line2">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line3">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line3">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line3">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line3">Subparagraf</p>
  <p class="line3">Subparagraf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена картинки на CSS. Анимация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908198/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @Air, на взгляд дилетанта (а ведь желательно, чтобы ответ был понятен и дилетантам) совершенно непонятно, как применить изложенное в приведённой ссылке к данному вопросу. т.е., требуются разъяснения, т.е. это **не** дубликат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `css` у псевдо класса `:hover` ограниченные возможности.

Обычно `:hover` Используют для воздействия родителя на дочерний элемент...

Можно на на соседа `.list:hover~.line` , но при условии иерархии расположен ниже и обязательно у этих элементов один родитель

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Federant', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.menu {
  width: 250px;
  background: rgb(151, 101, 101);
}

.list:hover~.line {
  background: rgb(11, 201, 101);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p class="list"> list</p>
  <p class="line"> line</p>
</div>
```

Во-втором варианте это не сработает

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Federant', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.menu {
  width: 250px;
  background: rgb(151, 101, 101);
}

.line:hover~.list {
  background: rgb(11, 201, 101);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p class="list"> list</p>
  <p class="line"> line</p>
</div>
```

Так же и в этом варианте не сработает

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Federant', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.menu {
  width: 250px;
  background: rgb(151, 101, 101);
}

.list:hover~.line {
  background: rgb(11, 201, 101);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p class="list"> list</p>
</div>

<p class="line"> line</p>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.list:hover ~ .line {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Пробуй так.

Когда ты делаешь это через пробел - ты будешь применять это к тем блокам, которые находятся *внутри* блока с классом .list

> div p – элементы p, являющиеся потомками div. (те, которые находятся внутри него)
>
> div ~ p – правые соседи: все p на том же уровне вложенности, которые
> идут после div.