# Hover эффект на текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы при наведении на текст менялась картинка и текст сам менял цвет. Я написал так, но не знаю как изменение цвета текста сделать после определенной картинки.

Kак это реализовать?

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/11.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/16.png);
}

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/5.png);
}

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/8.png);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  text1
</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  Text2
</p2>
<div class="pic" style="border-radius: 20px;"></div>
<p3 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  Text3
</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  Text4
</p4>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена картинки на CSS. Анимация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/908198/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Tinur, плодить вопросы... А лучше стары отредактировать

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сам текст менял цвет, достаточно прописать это в ховере:

```css
p:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>ТЕКСТ</p>
```

А чтобы все картинки менялись, надо поставить блок .pic ПОСЛЕ ВСЕХ абзацев, потому что символ ~ означает "элемент, идущий после", и если он идёт перед, то ховер не сработает.

Comment: а если нужно, чтобы картинки сами двигались и загорался текст, который относится к этой картинке? Как это реализовать, весь инет перерыл, ничего даже близкого нет. можете помочь?

Comment: @timur, что значит "сами"? Вам слайдер нужен?

Comment: да, просто хотел начать с простого наведения

Comment: @timur, что значит "весь инет перерыл, ничего даже близкого нет"? забиваете в поисковик "слайдер на css" - просто море вариантов предлагается

Comment: @я искал так, только суть в том, что мне нужно под-другому делать